# C# Changing Label Text to Listbox Selection Text

Tags: c#, text, listbox, label

So i have been browsing around the great mind of Google but have not found a working solution to this; I have a listbox (instanceSelection) and a label (instanceTxt). I want the instanceTxt to be the same as the instanceSelection's text when I select an item in the collection.

Here is the code line that I thought would work earlier:

```
private void instanceSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        instanceTxt.Text = (string)this.instanceSelection.SelectedValue.Text;
    }
```

But in one time it didn't change, and another code block it changed to "0". I also sometimes get a null error when using "ToString".

Thanks,
William

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void instanceSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

if(instanceSelection.SelectedIndex > -1)
     instanceTxt.Text = instanceSelection.Items[instanceSelection.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain why this worked? As in, why the conditional for -1? I don't understand this...

Comment: Sure. Some times it gives -1 value. So i put a if condition to check that for preventing indexoutofbound exception.